# Scene2D label setWrap is ignored

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a simple box that displays text and a button.
I'm trying to get the text to wrap within the table.
Unfortunately the text overflows the table and doesn't wrap.

I though this would be very simple, but it's becoming a pain.

```
Label description = SkinController.getInstance().getLabel(Strings.NoAdsDescription, Values.FONT_SCALE_SMALL);
description.setWrap(true);
description.setAlignment(Align.center);

TextButton buy = SkinController.getInstance().getTextButton(Strings.Buy);

table.add(description).maxWidth(table.getWidth() - (Values.PADDING_SMALL * 2f)).pad(Values.PADDING_SMALL).expandY().top().center();
table.row();
table.add(buy).pad(Values.PADDING_SMALL);
```

Comment: it might be that your labelWidth is bigger than the screen? I would try to use a set width to test if it is working. Then see where the problem lies. It's probably in the "table.add" line somewhere.

Comment: It's not wider than the screen but it's wider than the table. Although that's what wrap is for?

Comment: Try setting a fixed width for the Cell, when adding the Label.

Comment: Nope, still bugs. But I found that added .fill() at the end of the line where I add it, it works.

Now I have an issue with scroll-pane not being picked up in the json when it's obviously there. :-/.

Comment: set the width of the label seperately... That should solve the problem

Comment: I have also same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `prefWidth` instood of `maxWidth`

Sample:

```
mylabel.setWrap(true);
mylabel.setWidth(100);
table.add(mylabel).expandX().prefWidth( 350 );
```